#  How to call setContentView() explicitly from other method

Tags: android

In my application for an activity's `setContentview()` I set a class which extends `SurfaceView`.

At first when the app run I able to draw there on surface (bcz there i put Touch events in that class and using canvas i able to draw on that surface ), 
In a option menu click i want different drawings come on same screen/surface (means explicitly i want to draw circle or line on that same canvas)& it should be set to that surface.
but how can i do this?

Is there any way to call setcontview again then it may solve.
U can see my code http://pastebin.com/DZ0hcH3j here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call invalidate() on your view class. This will call your onDraw() eventually.

Comment: But in that class onDraw() is not a override methow. How it automatically call! Plz go throgh my code and suggest me a way.